# Problem with MvcContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I want to use MvcContrib Grid helper, but i stuck on the problem - it's not working.
I downloaded release for mvc 1, i have dll on my hard drive, i added a reference to my project, but i always getting following error:
Error   1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Grid' and no extension method 'Grid' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 if this is important
The question is: how correctly add this to my project?
Can you give me step by step instruction?
Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a `using` directive?  If the word, "Grid" has a red squiggly under it, right-click on it, and select "Resolve" from the menu that pops up.

Comment: I don't have such option in menu that pops up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have the reference to the MVcContrib dll added. See my sample app here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx

Note that a reference has been added in the solution to the dll.

Comment: i can't open your solution because i am using web developer express.
in my project i have  a folder 'References' where i have whole bunch of namespaces. I added mvccontrib to that folder and it sits there. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Have you add the namespace in your web.config ?

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
         ...
       <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI"/>
       <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Html"/>
       <add namespace="MvcContrib"/>
    </namespaces>
...
</pages>
```

Comment: @Sasha And also MvcContrib.UI.Grid ?

Comment: Make sure you close the view after you save and try to rebuild the project